# Swift 3 filterWithPredicate not working

Tags: ios, swift3

Unable to filter array of dictionaries using predicate here is my code and  i would like to filter array of dictionaries having key "category"

```
let searchText = searchTF.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")  
  if (searchText?.characters.count)!>0 {
   let pred = NSPredicate(format: "SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchTF.text!)
  let array = NSMutableArray()
 array.insert(dataArray as [AnyObject], at:NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, dataArray.count)) as IndexSet)
     dataArray.removeAllObjects()
     getedArray = NSMutableArray(array: array.filtered(using: pred))
  dataArray = getedArray.sortedArray(using: #selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_ :)))
            }
```

its giving error at last line i.e

getedArray = NSMutableArray(array: array.filtered(using: pred))
  NSArray).sortedArrayUsingSelector(#selector(self.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))

its giving error at last line **Use of unresolved identifier 'localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare'**

Comment: *Unable* in what way? Crash, compile error, unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @MaheshNarla You need to add that error

Comment: can not assign value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to type 'NSMutableArray'

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray` in Swift at all. Instead of `NSPredicate` use `filter`, `hasPrefix` and `lowercased` (as `[c]`). Your code is too cumbersome anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Achieved this by

```
let searchText = searchTF.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    if (searchText?.characters.count)!>0 {
        // Put your key in predicate that is "category"
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "category CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText!)
        let array = (dataArray as NSMutableArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        print ("array = \(array)")
        if(array.count == 0){
            searchTFActive = false;
        } else {
            searchTFActive = true;
        }
         self.aTable.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: You are making confusion here, in your question with filter you are using `beginswith` now you have post answer with `CONTAINS`, You need to really edit your question and give all the detail and output you want, this is not the correct way of asking a question.

Comment: And will you please tell me where this sort goes that you have ask continuously in my answers comment?

Comment: I doesn't what that, i'm just saying is from next time when you ask question please add all the require detail that you want including the output that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Swift native solution. `filteredArray` will contain the filtered and sorted array.

```
guard let searchText = searchTF.text, !searchText.isEmpty else { return }
let trimmedSearchText = searchText.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
let filteredArray = dataArray.filter( {($0["category"] as! String).lowercased().hasPrefix(trimmedSearchText) })
                             .sorted { ($0["category"] as! String).lowercased() < ($1["category"] as! String).lowercased()  }
```

The code assumes that there is always a value for key `category`. Consider to use a custom struct or class to avoid the casts to `String`.

Comment: this answer is nice but dataArray is a arrayOfDictiuonaries and i would like to filter that array having key "category" could you please update your answer

Comment: is this case sensitive?/

Comment: No it is not, `lowercased()` makes it case insensitive.

Comment: If want incasesensitive

Comment: It **is** incasesensitive